# What is the best way to pass an argument into a Func<> in C#?

Tags: c#, parameters, func

I have the following code:

```
public void Test(Request request, Func<IEnumerable<Building>> buildings)
{
   vm.Buildings = Helper.GenerateDropdownList(request.BuildingId,() => buildings());
}
```

I now want to pass an additional argument to the `buildings()` callback

```
public void Test(Request request, Func<IEnumerable<Building>> buildings)
{
   var cityId = GetCity();
   vm.Buildings = Helper.GenerateDropdownList(request.BuildingId,() => buildings(cityId));
}
```

what is the right way to type that parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `buildings` delegate will need to be a [`Func<T, TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) instead of a `Func<TResult>`.

Assuming `cityId` is an `int`:

```
public void Test(Request request, Func<int, IEnumerable<Building>> buildings)
{
   var cityId = GetCity();
   m.Buildings = Helper.GenerateDropdownList(request.BuildingId,
                                             () => buildings(cityId));
}
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more on how to include that extra city argument into the callback

Comment: +1 But I'd like to note that `() => buildings(GetCity())` is slightly cleaner since you don't need a closure around the local variable.